# HubFlow: certain HubFlow commands prompt me for my GitHub credentials multiple times. Is there a way around this?

Tags: git, github, git-flow, hubflow

I am currently learning the [HubFlow](http://datasift.github.com/gitflow/GitFlowForGitHub.html) way of managing versioning and workflow using Git and GitHub.

I created this [dummy repository](https://github.com/simkimsia/learnhubflow) to get some hands-on experience.

I have tried certain commands like

```
git hf update
```

I get prompted for my GitHub credentials multiple times.

Here is an example:

```
macair:learnhubflow simkimsia$ git hf update
Fetching origin
Already on 'master'
From https://github.com/simkimsia/learnhubflow
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Username: 
Password: 
Everything up-to-date
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
From https://github.com/simkimsia/learnhubflow
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating d76bec3..b351907
Fast-forward
 IMG_0001-w800-h600.png |  Bin 0 -> 192787 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 IMG_0001-w800-h600.png
Username: 
Password: 
Everything up-to-date
Switched to branch 'master'

Summary of actions:
- Changes from origin/master have been pulled into branch 'master'
- Changes from origin/develop have been pulled into branch 'develop'
- You are now on branch 'master'
```

**Is there a way for me to simply supply the GitHub credentials just once each time I used a HubFlow command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSH keys+URLs. If you already have an SSH key, [add it to your Github account](https://github.com/settings/ssh).

If you don't have an SSH key, Github provides [a nice guide walking you through creating a keypair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and authorizing your public key.

After you've added a public key to Github, you'll need to change your remotes to use the SSH URLs:

```
https://github.com/simkimsia/learnhubflow -> git@github.com:simkimsia/learnhubflow.git
```

Assuming that this is your `origin`, you can make the change with the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:simkimsia/learnhubflow.git
```

Now you'll be authenticated using your keypair instead of needing to type in your password. If you wish, you can set a password for your keypair so that someone who walks up to your unlocked computer can't push changes as you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. On top of what you suggested, I also had removed all the SSH keys I had previously in GitHub user settings before adding my current one on the machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or if it is difficult to maintain SSH Keys for multiple account you can cache password for 15 mins.

$ git config credential.helper cache

With this configuration once, you have to type your password only once and it will be in cache for next 15 minutes.